# DNS CNAME settings for pointing to custom domain (multi-tenant SaaS)

Tags: .htaccess, dns, multi-tenant, saas, cname

I'm new to DNS settings and hoping someone can help me here. I checked a few stackoverflow questions, but couldn't find a solution.

I'm creating a multi tenant SaaS application -  one code base, multiple db's. If my users were to have their own custom domains, what CNAME entries should I ask them to change in their DNS settings?
I **don't** want users to hardcode the IP address (using A Name) of my server in user domain settings. My app is hosted on apache webserver AWS Ec2.

Comment: " I checked a few stackoverflow questions, but couldn't find a solution." Because DNS questions are off topic as not related to programming which is the topic of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

CNAME records let you point at another domain or subdomain, but they aren't allowed to be pointing the apex (the root) of the domain at something, only a subdomain.

For instance, a CNAME can point subdomain.mydomain.com at anotherdomain.com, but it can't point mydomain.com at anotherdomain.com.

So you'll need to tell them to point a subdomain at a domain or subdomain attached to your server. Most likely, you'll want to tell them to point the www subdomain at your domain/subdomain.

I'd recommend having them point at a subdomain, as you may want a way to easily differentiate requests to custom domains vs your SaaS apps regular requests.

The DNS record for this would looks something like:

Type: CNAME, host: www, address: subdomain.yourdomain.com, TTL: 3600

There's also the issue of having them point the www subdomain, but not the apex domain. If someone forgets to enter www they'll be taken wherever the A record points (or it won't resolve, if there isn't one). Many registrars/dns providers will let you redirect through them, but not all. If not, they'll need to create their own virtual host to do that, or you'll have to tell them to point their A record at your server IP address.

Some providers also allow ALIAS records, which basically do some magic under the hood to let you point an apex domain at another domain/subdomain instead of an IP address. Heads up though, many DNS providers still don't offer this however, so you can't rely on it fully.

Finally, you'll need to handle receiving the requests on your app from custom domains. That'll depend entirely on how your app works, but one thing you can do (if you have a server-side app running) is to check the host header of requests and then return different responses depending on that.

If you're using more of a frontend app and requesting to an API, you can grab the custom domain of the request with window.location.hostname and send that with the API request to send back the right data.

Source:

I spend a lot of time dealing with this stuff while building [approximated.app](https://approximated.app) to solve this for people.